# how to create an outline of a text with fonts with separate polygons for each letter?

Tags: inkscape

I want the outline of text with the standard Windows font "Bahnschrift". I tried to convert it with "Path->Object to Path" and then setting fill to X and stroke to black, but looks like the font is constructed with separate polygons for each letter. See this example:

[image]

Top is Bahnschrift, and bottom is Arial which works fine.

Is it possible to calculate somehow automatically the outline of the top text, without intersections, and without doing it all manually for all the letters? And including the right outline for letters with holes, like the "e"?

Some letters are even kind of twisted internally, looks pretty bad:

[image]

So I guess an algorithm to detect if it is a real hole, or if it is a hole from such twists and to ignore it, could be difficult.

Comment: You can do Path > Combine, Path > Union.

Answer (score 0):

Select the complete character in question. Then select from the drop down menu:
Path intersection followed by path union. This fixes the character font outline problem where the outline crosses into the body of the character.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32520365)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).